# Changing the theme of Particles component(react tsparticles library) dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, particles, tsparticles

I am trying to change the color of my particles background and link dynamically.The theme only changes after I refresh the page for some reason.

this is my darkMode component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as Sun } from './Sun.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Moon } from './Moon.svg';
import './DarkMode.css';

const DarkMode = () => {
  const setDarkMode = () => {
    document.querySelector('body').setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    localStorage.setItem('selectedTheme', 'dark');
  };
  const setLightMode = () => {
    document.querySelector('body').setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
    localStorage.setItem('selectedTheme', 'light');
  };
  const selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme');

  if (selectedTheme === 'dark') setDarkMode();
  const toggleTheme = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) setDarkMode();
    else setLightMode();
  };
  return (
    <div className="dark_mode">
      <input
        className="dark_mode_input"
        type="checkbox"
        id="darkmode-toggle"
        onChange={toggleTheme}
        defaultChecked={selectedTheme === 'dark'}
      />
      <label className="dark_mode_label" for="darkmode-toggle">
        <Sun />
        <Moon />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DarkMode;
```

and this is my particle component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-tsparticles';
import { loadSlim } from 'tsparticles-slim';

import '../style/ParticlesBackground.css';

const ParticlesBackground = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('dark');
  console.log(theme);
  useEffect(() => {
    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme');
    if (savedTheme) {
      setTheme(savedTheme);
    }
  }, []);

  const particlesInit = useCallback(async (engine) => {
    await loadSlim(engine);
  }, []);

  const particlesLoaded = useCallback((container) => {
    console.log(container);
  }, []);

  const calculateThemeColor = (darkColor, lightColor) => {
    return theme === 'dark' ? darkColor : lightColor;
  };

  const particleColor = calculateThemeColor('#7e7c73', '#2e2e2e');
  const linkColor = calculateThemeColor('#e61717', '#140005');
  const bodyBackground = calculateThemeColor('#040720', '#454545');
  const particleOptions = {
    background: {
      color: {
        value: bodyBackground,
      },
    },
//OTHER PARTICLE OPTIONS
    particles: {
      color: {
        value: particleColor,
      },
      links: {
        color: linkColor,
        distance: 165,
        enable: true,
        opacity: 0.6,
        width: 1.3,
//OTHER PARTICLE OPTIONS
  };
  console.log(particleOptions);
  return (
    <div>
      <Particles
        id="tsparticles"
        init={particlesInit}
        loaded={particlesLoaded}
        options={particleOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default ParticlesBackground;
```

The localStorage variable doess change but visually nothing is being changed unless I refresh the page.